# Objective C - UIAlertView after login to enter email id if email id is null for ios

Tags: ios, facebook, email, facebook-login

in my code some times i get null value for email id when login with facebook if user is login with mobile number

so i want uialertview to enter email id and pass to my api link

```
- (void) fetchFacebookUserInfo {
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, name, id, gender"} ]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);

             NSLog(@"name:%@",[result objectForKey:@"name"]);
             NSLog(@"id:%@",[result objectForKey:@"id"]);
             NSLog(@"email:%@",[result objectForKey:@"email"]);

         if ([result objectForKey:@"email"]==NULL) {
// here i want uialertview for enter email id with validation and pass email id to my Callapi             
                 }
             } else {
                 [self CallApi:[result objectForKey:@"name"] :[result objectForKey:@"email"]];
             }
         }
     }];
  }
}
```

Comment: you can write in place of your comment - UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Project Name" message:@"Your message (Please login with email address)" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

Comment: but i dont want to force him to re login with email id... so its better i ask him to enter email id by showing alert with alertviewstyle

Comment: Than dear. if user is not register with email or user has not provided email id in his/her profile, thn FBSDK will not provide us. FBSDK will sent that parameter as nil.

Comment: yes exactly thats why i want ask manually enter email id from user

Comment: than you can set alert with input textfiled.

Comment: yes i have done this but dont know how to store this entered text from textfield...or may be i am doing something wrong

Comment: Let me give you answer.

Comment: Check my answer dear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define strName in **ViewController.h** file

```
NSString *strName;
```

Now in your method:-

```
    - (void) fetchFacebookUserInfo {
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, name, id, gender"} ]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);

                 NSLog(@"name:%@",[result objectForKey:@"name"]);
                 NSLog(@"id:%@",[result objectForKey:@"id"]);
                 NSLog(@"email:%@",[result objectForKey:@"email"]);

strName = [result objectForKey:@"name"];

             if ([result objectForKey:@"email"]==NULL) {
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:APP_NAME message:@"Please enter email id" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Submit" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
        alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
        [alertView show];
                     }
                 } else {
                     [self CallApi:strName:[result objectForKey:@"email"]];
                 }
             }
         }];
      }
    }
```

**Make sure you have set AlertViewDelegate in interface(.h file) as below **

```
@interface yourViewController:UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Now use **delegate method of UIAlertView** as below:-

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(buttonIndex == 0){
        if(![CommonMethod validateEmailWithString:[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text]){
            NsLog(@"Please enter valid email address");
        }else{
             [self callYourWebService:strName:[alertViewAtIndex:0].text];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you and make you happy.

Comment: my webservice is like [self callYourWebService:name:[alertViewAtIndex:0].text];    as per your coding i get email manually from user but the question is only how to pass facebook name on this webservice...debuger shows name field empty and [alertViewAtIndex:0].text  shows entered email id

Comment: Thank You thank You thank you very much...now i get it... :)

Comment: You can do same for me.